# Send multiple messages in Photoshop SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking, sdk, photoshop

I am using the Photoshop Connection SDK to get my iPad app connected to Photoshop.

*(The SDK with all sample iOS projects can be downloaded here if you want to look closer: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk.html)*

While I have it working, its hard for me to solve my issue as I don't entirely understand the networking between the iPad and Photoshop. So here is my issue:

```
NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"app.activeDocument.layers[0].name;"];
NSData *dataToSend = [s1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self sendJavaScriptMessage:dataToSend];
artLayerName_transaction = transaction_id -1;
```

There is a little snippet of code, to send a message asking for the name of layer at index 0. That works great. However, let's say I try and send the same message straight after that but for index 1 as well.

Both messages are sent, but only one returns its string. The string is returned here:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent;
```

If you see the example projects its just the same, each message with its own transaction id as well. The method goes through a bunch of decrypting and things to receive that string and then reaches this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:received_data length:received_length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (content != 1)
{
     if (transaction == artLayerName_transaction)
         {
              [self processLayerName:string];
              needOutput = NO;
         }
}
```

I've out the full method at the bottom for full analysing.

It checks that its receiving the specific message so I can then take the result (string, my layer name) and do what I like with it. However when I try and send more than one message with the same transaction id I only get one of the two results. In the code above, string gives me both my layer names, but the if statement is only called once.

Is there a known way around sending several messages at once? I have tried getting an array back rather than several strings without luck as well.

Apparently I need to modify the code to accept more then message. However I don't really understand the code well enough, so please also explain any of the principals behind it.

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
    NSInputStream * istream;
    switch(streamEvent)
    {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:;

            UInt8 buffer[1024];
            unsigned int actuallyRead = 0;

            istream = (NSInputStream *)aStream;
            if (!dataBuffer)
            {
                dataBuffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];
            }

            actuallyRead = [istream read:buffer maxLength:1024];

            [dataBuffer appendBytes:buffer length:actuallyRead];

            // see if we have enough to process, loop over messages in buffer
            while( YES )
            {

                // Did we read the header yet?
                if ( packetBodySize == -1 )
                {
                    // Do we have enough bytes in the buffer to read the header?
                    if ( [dataBuffer length] >= sizeof(int) ) {
                        // extract length
                        memcpy(&packetBodySize, [dataBuffer bytes], sizeof(int));
                        packetBodySize = ntohl( packetBodySize );       // size is in network byte order

                        // remove that chunk from buffer
                        NSRange rangeToDelete = {0, sizeof(int)};
                        [dataBuffer replaceBytesInRange:rangeToDelete withBytes:NULL length:0];
                    }
                    else {
                        // We don't have enough yet. Will wait for more data.
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // We should now have the header. Time to extract the body.
                if ( [dataBuffer length] >= ((NSUInteger) packetBodySize) )
                {
                    // We now have enough data to extract a meaningful packet.
                    const int kPrologLength = 16;
                    char *buffer = (char *)[dataBuffer bytes];

                    // if incoming message is color change, then don't display message
                    BOOL needOutput = YES;

                    // fetch the communication status
                    unsigned long com_status = *((unsigned long *)(buffer + 0));
                    com_status = ntohl( com_status );

                    // decrypt the message
                    size_t decryptedLength = (size_t) packetBodySize - 4;  // don't include com status

                    int skip_message = 0;

                    if (com_status == 0 && sCryptorRef)
                    {
                        PSCryptorStatus decryptResult = EncryptDecrypt (sCryptorRef, false, buffer+4, decryptedLength, buffer+4, decryptedLength, &decryptedLength);

                        if (kCryptorSuccess != decryptResult)
                        {
                            // failed to decrypt.  Ingore messageg and disconnect
                            skip_message = 1;
                            [self logMessage:@"ERROR:  Decryption failed.  Wrong password.\n" clearLine:NO];
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (com_status != 0)
                        [self logMessage:@"ERROR: Problem with communication, possible wrong password.\n" clearLine:NO];

                        if (!sCryptorRef)
                        [self logMessage:@"ERROR: Cryptor Ref is NULL, possible reason being that password was not supplied or password binding function failed.\n" clearLine:NO];
                    }

                    // Interpret encrypted section
                    if (!skip_message)
                    {
                        // version, 32 bit unsigned int, network byte order
                        unsigned long protocol_version = *((unsigned long *)(buffer + 4));
                        protocol_version = ntohl( protocol_version );

                        if (protocol_version != 1)
                        {
                            // either the message is corrupted or the protocol is newer.
                            [self logMessage:@"Incoming protocol version is different the expected. (or the message is corrupted.)  Not processing.\n" clearLine:NO];
                            skip_message = 1;
                        }

                        if (!skip_message)
                        {
                            // transaction, 32 bit unsigned int, network byte order
                            unsigned long transaction = *((unsigned long *)(buffer + 8));
                            transaction = ntohl( transaction );

                            // content type, 32 bit unsigned int, network byte order
                            unsigned long content = *((unsigned long *)(buffer + 12));
                            content = ntohl( content );

                            unsigned char *received_data = (unsigned char *)(buffer+kPrologLength);
                            int received_length = (decryptedLength-(kPrologLength-4));

                            if (content == 3) // image data
                            {
                                // process image data
                                unsigned char image_type = *((unsigned char *)received_data);
                                [self logMessage:@"Incoming data is IMAGE.  Skipping\n" clearLine:NO];

                                if (image_type == 1) // JPEG
                                {
                                    [self logMessage:@"By the way, incoming image is JPEG\n" clearLine:NO];
                                }
                                else if (image_type == 2) // Pixmap
                                {
                                    [self logMessage:@"By the way, incoming image is Pixmap\n" clearLine:NO];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    [self logMessage:@"Unknown image type\n" clearLine:NO];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Set the response string
                                NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:received_data length:received_length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                //NSLog(@"string: %@\n id:%li", string, transaction);

                                // see if this is a response we're looking for
                                if (content != 1)
                                {                                    
                                    if (transaction == foregroundColor_subscription || transaction == foregroundColor_transaction)
                                    {
                                        [self processForegroundChange:string];
                                        needOutput = NO;
                                    }
                                    if (transaction == backgroundColor_subscription || transaction == backgroundColor_transaction)
                                    {
                                        [self processBackgroundChange:string];
                                        needOutput = NO;
                                    }
                                    if (transaction == tool_transaction)
                                    {
                                        [self processToolChange:string];
                                        needOutput = NO;
                                    }
                                    if (transaction == artLayerName_transaction)
                                    {
                                        [self processLayerName:string];
                                        needOutput = NO;
                                    }
                                }
                                //Tells me about every event thats happened (spammy tech nonsence, no good for user log)
                                //if (needOutput) [self logMessage:string clearLine:NO];
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    // Remove that chunk from buffer
                    NSRange rangeToDelete = {0, packetBodySize};
                    [dataBuffer replaceBytesInRange:rangeToDelete withBytes:NULL length:0];

                    // We have processed the packet. Resetting the state.
                    packetBodySize = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Not enough data yet. Will wait.
                    break;
                }
            }

            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:;
            [self closeStreams];
            [self logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ End encountered, closing stream.\n", outputMessage.text] clearLine:NO];
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        case NSStreamEventNone:
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

While this has worked, it has bumped me into another issue. I looked at the psconnection sample and saw what you were talking about, however I haven't been using the full framework but have it connect like in the other sample projects. I very simply increase my transaction id by 1 every time it comes to process a layer name such as in the code above.

Like this:

```
if (transaction == docName_transaction)
{
     docName_transaction++;
     [self processDocName:string];
}
```

This works for the most part, however if I do this to another transaction id at the same time I get overlap. Meaning I end up processing the result for one id at the wrong time. Say I am getting both the total number of docs and the name of each one.

So I have two if statements like above, but I end up processing the total docs in both if statements and I can't see how to atop this overlap. Its fairly important to be able to receive multiple messages at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded samples, and as far as i can see, you should use unique transaction IDs for transactions that are waiting for response.

I mean if you send layer_name request with transactionID 1, you cannot use 1, until it's response is received.

So better case will be, store your transactionID's in a Dictionary (transactionID as key), and message type as value.

just like:

transactions[transaction_id] = @"layername";

and when you receive response:

use: 
transactions[transaction_id] to get the message type (ex: layername) behave according to this.

You can also put some other details to transactions dictionary (you can put a dictionary containing all information, which command, on which object, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, not sure I follow though. Are you suggesting I have a dictionary of transactionIDs? What I am trying to avoid is having dozens of transactionIDs. Also, I don't even know how many I need, every photoshop document could have a different number of layers for example, so I have no way of knowing how many ids I need.

Comment: As I understand you cannot use same transactionID again, unless you get the reply from first one. So you can either wait for the answer from the first one, or you can use a dictionary to use many transactionIDs at once. (you will have a lot of transactionIDs, but you will map them to your limited set of actions)

Comment: How am I supposed to use a transactionID for each though when I don't necessarily know how many times I need to message photoshop? I might get info such as the file has 12 layers, but I can't declare these transactionIDs on the fly as they are used class wide and not in a single method.

Comment: Josh, you will declare transactionID as integer, and increase it by one each time you send message. (No pre-declertion). You can check out psconnection sample from sdk, which does a similar thing. It uses a array called _sentTransations.

Comment: THis solution did work, however down the line it has resulted in another issue, which I have detailed at the end of the original question. Appreciate it if you took a quick look.

Comment: @JoshKahane: you can try to seperate transactionIDs by groups, I mean docName_transaction starts from 0, but number_of_docs can start from 1000, another operation can start from 5000 etc. So they will not overlap.